# Insert multiple rows with same common ID

Tags: php, mysql

I currently am inserting multiple rows at once. I have an "id" column in the "agreement" table which is set to auto increment. This is, obviously, creating a new id for each row inserted.

Is there a way to insert all rows at once with the same ID?

```
if ($stmt = $mysqli->prepare("INSERT agreement (start, end, customer, manufacturer, item_number, item_description) VALUES (?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?)")) {
    $stmt->bind_param("ssssss", $start, $end, $customer, $manufacturer, $number, $description);
    for ($i = 0; $i < count($_POST['item']); $i++) {
        $number = $_POST['item'][$i];
        $description = $_POST['description'][$i];
        $theid2 = $theid[$i];
        $stmt->execute();
    }
    $stmt->close();
}
// show an error if the query has an error
else {
    echo "ERROR: Could not prepare SQL statement 1.";
}


// redirect the user
}
$mysqli->error;
$mysqli->close();
```

Answer (score 0):

If this was oracle the answer would be yes, but MySQL doesn't have sequences.  To do this you need a source of the unique sequence to use for your set of records.  The simplest is to insert into another table and get the auto incremented key from that to use as your id.